# Why does x print as 0 for this code forces problem?

Tags: python

```
n = int(input())
x = 0
operations = ["++", "--"]
lst = []
for i in range(0, n):
    statements = input().split()
    lst.append(statements)
for statement in lst:
    if operations[0] in lst:
        x += 1
    if operations[1] in lst:
        x -= 1
print(x)
```

[CodeForces Link](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/282/A)

How do I make it so if the users input contains "++" it adds 1 to x and if it contains "--" it will subtract 1 from x?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Your posted code hangs, waiting for input.  We are not responsible to provide a failing test case: that's your job.  Make it a simple assignment statement in place of the input.

Comment: If you tag a question as `python`, there's no need to add `(PYTHON)` to the title. You loop over `lst`, getting its values in `statement`, but you don't use `statement` in that block, only `lst` itself, which means you end up performing the same operation `len(lst)` times with no use for `statement` (and if `lst` happens to have both `++` and `--`, the two statements cancel each other out)

Answer (score 0):

`if operations[0] in lst:` and `if operations[1] in lst:` will both return True, so you are adding 1 and substracting 1 in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your second for loop isn't doing what you're looking for. You are checking to see if `'++'` is in the `lst` and checking the same for `'--'`.

You are already looping over the `statement` in  `lst`, so there is no reason to do that check. Instead you can do:

```py
for statement in lst:
    if statement == operations[0]:
        x += 1
    elif statement == operations[1]:
        x -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the if statements do:

```
if statement == operations[0]:
  x += 1
#And so on...
```

Your if statements are checking if there is a `++` or `--` in the whole list, not each statement.